# Magento 2 Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I just updated to 2.3 and when i try to "setup:uprade" i'm getting next error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`project`.`catalog_product_entity_int`, CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELET), query was: INSERT INTO 
>               catalog_product_entity_int(attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, `value`)
>               VALUES 
>               (:attribute_id0,:store_id0,:entity_id0,:value0),(:attribute_id1,:store_id1,:entity_id1,:value1),(:attribute_id2,:store_id2,:entity_id2,:value2),(:attribute_id3,:store_id3,:entity_id3,:value3)
>               ON duplicate KEY UPDATE `value` = VALUES(`value`)

But cant i cant find 'CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID' entry in this table? How can i solve this?
[image]

Comment: same issue here with table quote_address

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check with catalog_product_entity table. I was check with this table its belongs to `CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID`

Comment: can you pls explain the steps to do that\