# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: magento2, database, products

When I update any product from Magento admin panel, the following error appear:

```
SQL STATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db name`.`catalog_product_entity_int`, CONSTRAINT `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ROW_ID_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ROW_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`row_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`ro), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_int` (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = VALUES(`value`)
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running it on Magento Cloud, it's recommended to disable `synchronous_replication` in your `.magento.env.yaml`.

The product changes or CSV import causes an **integrity constraint violation** when there is a sync between the master and slave DBs.

```
DATABASE_CONFIGURATION: 
      _merge: true 
      slave_connection: 
        default: 
          synchronous_replication: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check with catalog_product_entity table.

I check with this table its belongs to `CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID`

I already post my answer here - [Magento 2 Cannot add or update a child row](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269317/magento-2-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row)

Comment: but what i do to remove this error

Comment: please check with table belongs CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID or not. if not than added to this.